# JavaFX: TextFlow with dynamic column wrapping

Tags: java, multiple-columns, javafx-8

I'm looking for an approach to let `TextFlow` wrap its content to two or multiple columns dynamically and (optional) evenly. Currently I need a starting point or a hint to the right direction.

Two modes are of interest here:

- **balanced  column heights** so that the heights of the content in each column are approximately equal
- **with constrained maximum column height** and then lay out content starting at the first column and creating as many columns as necessary, possibly overflowing to the right

In terms of text flow, *columns* are a special case of the more general requirement: **text flow through multiple layout boxes** with the above mentioned modes.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be tricky with a TextFlow.  As an alternative, you might want to consider using a [WebView with multi-column css](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multi-column_layouts).

Comment: I'm also interested to know if you found a way to make textflow to make columns out of the overflowing text or not?

using WebView is not an option for me as it has way too much overhead and has own rendering problems where I need it.

Comment: @mohamnag I agree with you. Unfortunately I cannot give you a solution here.
Maybe this question rather tends to be a feature request...